# Programmatically getting the current Visual Studio IDE solution directory from addins

Tags: c#, visual-studio, solution, envdte, vs-extensibility

I have some tools that perform updates on .NET solutions, but they need to know the directory where the solution is located.

I added these tools as External Tools, where they appear in the IDE Tools menu, and supplying `$(SolutionDir)` as an argument. This works fine.

However, I want these tools to be easier to access in the IDE for the user through a custom top level menu (for which I created a Visual Studio integration package project) and through a context menu on solution nodes (for which I created a Visual Studio add-in project).  I'm looking for a way to get the current solution directory through these contexts.

I tried getting the solution information from the `VisualStudio.DTE` object:

```
EnvDTE.DTE dte = (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
```

But, this returns the solution directory for the add ins, not the current solution.

I tried echoing `$(SolutionDir)` and reading it back:

```
System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "echo $(SolutionDir)");

// The following commands are needed to redirect the standard output.
// This means that it will be redirected to the Process.StandardOutput StreamReader.
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
// Do not create the black window.
procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
// Now we create a process, assign its ProcessStartInfo and start it
System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
// Get the output into a string
string result = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

But, this returned the directory for the IDE, not the current solution.

I didn't see any relevant information in the solution node `CommandBar`.

Alternatively, if there was a way to programmatically access the defined Visual Studio external tools and launch them (using the already defined macro arguments), that would work.

What is the solution?

Comment: 2+ again apparently I'm stalking you here With this DTE madness lol

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> EnvDTE.DTE dte =
>   (EnvDTE.DTE)System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE");
>   string solutionDir =
>   System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(dte.Solution.FullName);
>
> But, this returns the solution
>   directory for the add ins, not the
>   current solution.

Your approach to get the directory is good. What's wrong is the way you get the `VisualStudio.DTE` object. Where is this code called? I assume it is in your add-in. Do you execute (debug) your add-in in Visual Studio which opens another instance of Visual Studio where you open your solution? So you have two instances of Visual Studio.

The `GetActiveObject("VisualStudio.DTE")` gets a random Visual Studio instance. In your case, it is apparently Visual Studio with an add-in project since you get path to your add-in. That's for explanation what would be the reason of your problem.

The correct way to get `DTE` is very simple. In fact, your add-in already has reference to DTE in which it runs (that is, in which the solution is opened). It is stored in a global variable _applicationObject in your add-in connect class. It is set when your add-in starts in the `OnConnection` event handler. So all you need is to call:

```
string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
```

Comment: Thanks Peter, that was precisely the issue and solution!  Now I'll look for a way to get the output from executing the tools via the custom menus to go to the output window instead of a separate window and all will work perfectly.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

With Peter's push in the right direction, I set up the context menu addin to launch an external tool with the solution directory, and output the results to the output pane.  Some example blurb from the add in:

```
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This method implements the OnConnection method of the IDTExtensibility2 interface. Receives notification that the Add-in is being loaded.</summary>
    ///
    /// <param term='application'>Root object of the host application.</param>
    /// <param term='connectMode'>Describes how the Add-in is being loaded.</param>
    /// <param term='addInInst'>Object representing this Add-in.</param>
    /// <seealso class='IDTExtensibility2' />
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    public void OnConnection(object application, ext_ConnectMode connectMode, object addInInst, ref Array custom)
    {
        _applicationObject = (DTE2)application;
        _addInInstance = (AddIn)addInInst;

        // Get the solution command bar
        CommandBar solutionCommandBar = ((CommandBars)_applicationObject.CommandBars)["Solution"];

        // Set up the main InCode
        CommandBarPopup solutionPopup = (CommandBarPopup)solutionCommandBar.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlPopup, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
        solutionPopup.Caption = "InCode";

        // Add solution updater submenu
        CommandBarControl solutionUpdaterControl = solutionPopup.Controls.Add(MsoControlType.msoControlButton, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, System.Reflection.Missing.Value, 1, true);
        solutionUpdaterControl.Caption = "Update Solution";
        updateSolutionMenuItemHandler = (CommandBarEvents)_applicationObject.Events.get_CommandBarEvents(solutionUpdaterControl);
        updateSolutionMenuItemHandler.Click += new _dispCommandBarControlEvents_ClickEventHandler(updateSolution_Click);
    }

    // The event handlers for the solution submenu items
    CommandBarEvents updateSolutionMenuItemHandler;

    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This property gets the solution updater output pane.</summary>
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected OutputWindowPane _solutionUpdaterPane = null;
    protected OutputWindowPane SolutionUpdaterPane
    {
        get
        {
            if (_solutionUpdaterPane == null)
            {
                OutputWindow outputWindow = _applicationObject.ToolWindows.OutputWindow;
                foreach (OutputWindowPane loopPane in outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes)
                {
                    if (loopPane.Name == "Solution Updater")
                    {
                        _solutionUpdaterPane = loopPane;
                        return _solutionUpdaterPane;
                    }
                }
                _solutionUpdaterPane = outputWindow.OutputWindowPanes.Add("Solution Updater");
            }
            return _solutionUpdaterPane;
        }
    }

    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This method handles clicking on the Update Solution submenu.</summary>
    ///
    /// <param term='inputCommandBarControl'>The control that is source of the click.</param>
    /// <param term='handled'>Handled flag.</param>
    /// <param term='cancelDefault'>Cancel default flag.</param>
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void updateSolution_Click(object inputCommandBarControl, ref bool handled, ref bool cancelDefault)
    {
        try
        {
            // set up and execute solution updater thread
            UpdateSolutionDelegate updateSolutionDelegate = UpdateSolution;
            updateSolutionDelegate.BeginInvoke(UpdateSolutionCompleted, updateSolutionDelegate);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // put exception message in output pane
            SolutionUpdaterPane.OutputString(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected delegate void UpdateSolutionDelegate();

    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This method launches the solution updater to update the solution.</summary>
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void UpdateSolution()
    {
        try
        {
            // set up solution updater process
            string solutionDir = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(_applicationObject.Solution.FullName);
            System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(@"SolutionUpdater.exe", solutionDir);
            procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            System.Diagnostics.Process proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
            proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;

            // execute the solution updater
            proc.Start();

            // put solution updater output to output pane
            SolutionUpdaterPane.OutputString(proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd());
            SolutionUpdaterPane.OutputString("Solution update complete.");
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // put exception message in output pane
            SolutionUpdaterPane.OutputString(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    /// <summary>This method completing the update solution thread.</summary>
    ///
    /// <param name="ar">IAsyncResult.</param>
    ///--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    protected void UpdateSolutionCompleted(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        try
        {
            if (ar == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("ar");

            UpdateSolutionDelegate updateSolutionDelegate = ar.AsyncState as UpdateSolutionDelegate;
            Trace.Assert(updateSolutionDelegate != null, "Invalid object type");

            updateSolutionDelegate.EndInvoke(ar);
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            // put exception message in output pane
            SolutionUpdaterPane.OutputString(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Nope, didn't find a way to poll an external process, I ended up doing what I needed as an internal process in a VS Package.

Comment: I have a solution for the result polling (or rather stream the output into the output pane), at least when using a VSPackage. Rather out of scope for this question (and wont fit here..), so perhaps you can open a new question and I'll answer there.

Comment: OK, I threw together a separate question for this, if your answer looks good I'll accept! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8345636/is-there-a-good-way-to-stream-the-results-from-an-external-process-into-a-visual